# Large overhead for reading pickled panda to R

Tags: python, r, pickle

I have a 10GB `.pkl` file, which contains four pandas. Following advice in [this blog post](https://www.ankuroh.com/programming/data-analysis/reading-pickle-file-in-r/), I try to load it in R. R takes up to 25GB of memory for this process and I wonder whether the computational overhead arises. How to make this more feasible? I could save as csv but, but there should be a better solution, no?

For reference, the post suggests to save a python function `read_pickle_file.py`:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_pickle_file(file):
    pickle_data = pd.read_pickle(file)
    return pickle_data
```

and then in R:

```
require("reticulate")

source_python("pickle_reader.py")
pickle_data <- read_pickle_file("C:/tsa/dataset.pickle")
```

Comment: Reading a 10GB pickle file is going to consume a lot of resource regardless of whether it's being invoked indirectly or not. Have you tried comparing the time it take to do natively verses via R? There are also different pickle "protocols" and some are faster than others. Do you know which one is being used to create the pickle file>

Comment: You might have better luck converting the file to Parquet and reading it in with R’s Arrow library but I don’t have any experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

The only workable solution for me was to export from Python using `feather`, which allows to also import from R. Resulted in (almost) no overhead (but is not a proper answer to my question, if you have better one I'd be happy to accept).

A `feather` tutorial can be found [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/)